# Correct tree-sitter based indentation for d-ts-mode.el

Tags: indentation, tree-sitter

I've put together a d-ts-mode for the D programming language at https://gitlab.com/per.nordlow/elisp/-/blob/main/d-ts-mode.el.

The indentation doesn't work for all cases. Does anyone have advice on how to correct them?